# Switching between multiple FTP accounts for a project in netbeans 6.9

Tags: ftp, editor, netbeans-6.9

Hi i have a project which is linked to multiple mirror ftp accounts. For example, i have configured three ftp accounts Local server, development server, production server. Whenever i edit a file in my localhost, i can upload them to server by right clicking the file and selecting upload.

By default, when you right click a project,->set configuration -> customize, you can select which FTP you want to use for uploading for current project. Every time,  i do a correction, i add a few features i want to do the following. I want to upload it to any one of the ftp servers. For example, important corrections can be uploaded in production server, but new feature file should not be uploaded in production. What i do is, i change the configuration setting everytime when i want to upload to different server. This is really a headache for me.

Is there any plugin available which shows a simple drop down menu when i click upload, so i can choose which FTP should i upload it. Any similar functionalities or any other alternative suggestions for this problem is really appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am not sure about the 6.9. But it is now possible with 7.3(my current version). See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9d7M7MnA3AI

Answer (score 0):

http://kenai.com/projects/nb-remotefs/sources/mercurial/content/remotefs-ftp/src/org/netbeans/modules/remotefs/ftp/client/FTPClient.java?rev=44
You can modify the source in such a way that to accept a host name.Currently in this piece of code
the host name is taken from a class file by reading the config(I think so).So making a change to your requiremtn
will not be that much difficult.